Scale in konva js with background image
I want to scale up and scale down stage in konva js. I have a background image attached to konva container so that should scale also. I also need to get correct mouse position , I have a code for that also. But still something's not right , I am not sure if  I am going in the correct direction
    scaleUp() {
      const scaleFactor = 1.01;

      const stageParentDiv = document.getElementById("canvasStage");
      var pointer = this.stage.getPointerPosition();


      const currentScale = this.stage.scaleX();
      let newScale = currentScale + 0.2

      // Apply new scale to stage
      this.stage.scaleX(newScale);
      this.stage.scaleY(newScale);


      let sw = this.stage.width() * newScale
      let sh = this.stage.height() * newScale

      // Update background image size to match this.stage scaling
      console.log(this.stage.width());
      stageParentDiv.style.width = `${sw}px`;
      stageParentDiv.style.height = `${sh}px`;

      // this.stage.width(sw);
      // this.stage.height(sh);
      // Redraw the this.stage to reflect changes

      this.stage.draw()

    }

   getUnscaledMousePosition(event) {
      const mouseX = event.offsetX / this.stage.scaleX();
      const mouseY = event.offsetY / this.stage.scaleY();
      return { x: mouseX, y: mouseY };
    },


The most straightforward approach is to have the background image in the stage. You then do not have the overhead of computing a new css position and scale for the image as it will move and scale with the stage.
